# לישב בסוכה the second night if you've been in the sukkah continuously

Tags: blessing, yom-tov, sukkah, chutz-laaretz

Let's say you were in the sukkah on the first day of Sukkos, outside Israel, and said לישב בסוכה.  You have not interrupted your stay in the sukkah.  Now it's the second night.  Do you say the bracha again?

My assumption was that you do make a new bracha.  From the point of view of sefeika deyoma, yesterday was not Sukkos and there was no mitzva to sit in the sukkah.  I would have thought that this bracha is no different from kiddush, or shehecheyanu, or על אכילת מצה on the second night of Pesach.

However, R' Moshe Feinstein [OC 4:101](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=191) (at the end of the answer to the first question) takes for granted that you do *not* make a new bracha at kiddush if you've been in the sukkah continuously.  At first I thought maybe he was talking about Shabbos Chol Hamoed, but he explicitly says he's talking about the second night of Yom Tov.  The point comes up tangentially to the main topic of the teshuva and so he doesn't elaborate on his reasoning.

Does anyone address my argument (either to explain why it's wrong or to disagree with R' Moshe)?

Comment: I think we discussed this in a comment thread somewhere

Comment: I don't remember discussing this question.  We did discuss using a similar trick to make early Shemini Atzeres and avoid the Maharil's issue (incidentally my LOR approved of that trick and I plan to do it in a few hours).  But the sefeika deyoma component isn't relevant there.  I'm pretty sure I didn't see this Igros Moshe until this year.

Comment: Well, I can't find any threads now, but I have also wondered this for a number of years and never found any explicit sources. The best I found was the mishna berura 639 47 as if you could just say it once (not twice) but it's not a great diyuk

Comment: Maybe RMF is talking about in Israel when the second night is Friday night so you're making kiddush without sfeika deyoma (just kidding)

Comment: @DoubleAA the Shar Hatzion (number88) on that MB states explicitly that this could work even if it was for seven days straight, so that would encompass the second day as well.  So R Moshe and the MB agree

Comment: @Chatzkel no proof, he may be talking about israel (after all he didn't say 8 days)

Comment: I’d imagine that he would say so if he meant that

Comment: The eighth day we don’t say a bracha in chutz laaretz

Comment: @Chatzkel He wasn't being detailed, he was giving a general rule. If someone said in a drasha "שבעת ימים נאכל מצות" do you say "aha he didn't specify only in israel!" Here the point is the bracha can last indefinitely.

Comment: Sorry one more source that I remembered but I couldn't find before because I was looking in the wrong spot. MA and PMG to 639 discuss saying kiddush a few minutes early the second night. MA seems to think leshev too, not just bread eating, must be after tzeis (meaning a leshev from day 1 won't help). This seems like a stronger diyuk, and the mishna berura himself seems to agree in the beiur halacha @Chatzkel that should be a stira to you

Comment: Why would the second day be different from the third?

Comment: @shmosel Because the second day might be the first day.  From a sfeika deyoma perspective yesterday was chol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kovetz halachos (Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky) says like you that 2nd day night you make a new bracha because by sfaika diyoma we look at it as if yesterday wasn't yom tov.
Ive seen the ashrei ish that brings Rav Elyashev who said on this case you wont make a new bracha, but says however the Or Sameach implies you do. It doesn't bring an explanation in his psak. However the haga there said to look in the Chashukei Chemed (Rav Yitschak Zilberstein) on meseches sukka who discusses all the tzadim.

The Chashukei Chemed quotes in Rav Elyashiv's name that you don't say a new bracha because of ספק ברכות להקל.  Chazal established that you should say kiddush and shehecheyanu again, but we don't extrapolate.  This applied even when Yom Tov Sheini was a real safek.  The Shevet Halevi says it a bit differently and implies that they would have said a bracha, but now that we have a fixed calendar we wouldn't anymore, because again we don't extrapolate from kiddush and shehecheyanu.

The Or Sameach brings a complicated limud from the Gemara in Sukkah that I can't reproduce here and comes out that you do say a bracha.

Finally the Chashukei Chemed quotes R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach who says that "יתכן" you would say a bracha, and then, adding in the Ta"z who says that you make a bracha on each new meal (which we don't usually hold like), comes out that it would be ok to say a new bracha.

Comment: Thank you!  I hope it's ok I edited in what the Chashukei Chemed says.  If you don't like it I can post it as a new answer.  Either way the +100 is yours

Comment: @Heshy thank you for telling me what  hashekei chemed say

Comment: Still rather strange that there is a silence in premodern sources.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree but if you want to use that as an argument in favor of the "default" answer, which answer do you think that is?  Same as kiddush last night or same as any other night?  I can see either way.

Comment: @DoubleAA When siddurim print "on sukkos add this bracha" under the Friday night kiddush, they don't add "unless you said it earlier and have been in the sukkah since then" even though everyone besides the Taz agrees to that